# Simple Workflow question in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I'm new to workflows, so please excuse the novice question.

I set up a workflow on a document library configured to send an email when a new item is created. When I create a new document in this library, the email gets sent as expected. However, when I create a folder in this library, the workflow doesn't run. If I look at Workflow Status for the new folder, I don't see the workflow attached.

Is there anything special I need to do to configure this Workflow to kick-off when a folder is created and not just items?  If this is something that must be done with code-behind, I can go that route, but it doesn't seem like something that would require code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/MOSS_FolderContentTypeWF.aspx